# How do I pass information across wxPython frames?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I use wxPython to create a parent window "A" (a wx.Frame).

Within "A", I create a child (again a wx.Frame) dialog-like popup window "B".

Whenever I press a given button in the parent "A", I call this code:

```
import windowB as bb

class windowA (wx.Frame):

    ... some other methods go here...

    def on_data_setup(self, event):
        os.remove("tmp.tmp")
        popUpWindow = bb.popUp(None, title='Data Manager')
        popUpWindow.Show()
        while not os.path.exists("tmp.tmp"):
            time.sleep(1)
        with open("tmp.tmp","r") as ifh:
            l = ifh.readlines()
        print l
```

where windowB is contained in another file and it looks like:

```
class windowB (wx.Frame):
    ...
    def on_exit(self,event):
        with open("tmp.tmp","w") as ofh:
            ofh.write("test")
        self.Close()
```

This obviously does not word because as I call 'sleep' in the parent class, the whole program freezes - and I need to kill it as I can't interact with the child "B" neither :(.

Also, passing information via temp files is very inefficient.

The point is, I need my child/popUp window B to pass information back to the parent window A when I close it (B).. How can I achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using references is an easy way to communicate between wxpython frames. The following example creates a frame called 'Parent.' The parent frame creates a child frame and  saves a reference to it. You should probably never need to write information to disk to exchange it within the same process.

```
import wx


class Parent(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="parent frame")
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="click to send a message to the child frame")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)
        self.Show()
        self.CenterOnScreen(wx.BOTH)

        self.child_frame = None  # type: wx.Frame
        self.create_child_frame()

    def create_child_frame(self):
        child = wx.Frame(self, title="child frame")
        child.text = wx.TextCtrl(child)
        child.Show()
        child.SetPosition(self.GetRect().GetBottomLeft())
        # save a reference to the child frame on the parent
        self.child_frame = child

    def send_message_to_child(self, msg):
        # re-open the child frame if it's been closed
        if not bool(self.child_frame):
            self.create_child_frame()
        # accessing child frame attributes from the parent frame
        self.child_frame.text.SetValue(f"Message from parent frame: '{msg}'")

    def on_btn(self, evt):

        with wx.TextEntryDialog(self,
                                "Enter a message to pass to the child frame") as dialog:  # type: wx.TextEntryDialog
            if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                msg = dialog.GetValue()
                self.send_message_to_child(msg)


app = wx.App()
parent = Parent()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: mmm... yes, but my problem is asynchronous communication from the child to the parent.
i.e. when I am done populating the child's textCrtls, and I am ready to close the child window, I need to send all the info I typed in to the parent

Comment: @EffePelosa being asynchronous doesn't limit the use of references

Comment: Let me rephrase: I can reference the child Frame from the parent, and send info to it through a reference. I don't get how, from the child window, I can send data back to the parent..

Comment: you should update your question to reflect what you actually want to accomplish. self.GetParent() will return the frame's parent window

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would go ahead and post this as it helped me solve a somewhat similar problem...

When needing to update Main Window from a child window... See the updated script below:

```
import wx


class MainPage(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="parent frame")
        btn = wx.Button(self, size=(200, 20), pos=(80,160), label="click to send a message ")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_btn)
        #self.CenterOnScreen(VERTICAL)
        MainPage.text = wx.TextCtrl(self,size=(360, 140), pos=(10,10))
        self.Show()
        

        self.child_frame = None  # type: wx.Frame
        self.create_child_frame()

    def create_child_frame(self):
        child = wx.Frame(self, title="child frame")
        child.text = wx.TextCtrl(child)
        child.Show()
        child.SetPosition(self.GetRect().GetBottomLeft())
        # save a reference to the child frame on the parent
        self.child_frame = child

    def send_message_to_child(self, msg):
        # re-open the child frame if it's been closed
        if not bool(self.child_frame):
            self.create_child_frame()
        # accessing child frame attributes from the parent frame
        self.child_frame.text.SetValue(f"Message from child frame: '{msg}'")
        self.text.SetValue(f"Message from child frame: '{msg}'")

    def on_btn(self, evt):

        with wx.TextEntryDialog(self,
                                "Enter a message to pass to the child frame") as dialog:  # type: wx.TextEntryDialog
            if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
                msg = dialog.GetValue()
                self.send_message_to_child(msg)


app = wx.App()
parent = MainPage()
app.MainLoop()
```